# Magento accordion tabs in quickview close function

Tags: magento-1.9, quickview

I have Amasty Quickview extension on my site which opens a product in a frame.

There, my tabs are all closed. When a tab is clicked, it opens and displays the panel content. However you can't close the tab. The only way it closes is by opening another one.

Is there a way to assign a `display:none;` style to the panel, when the tab is clicked again? I know the issue might be that it is using the same CSS for when you are on the product page, and one tab is always displayed.

If the solution is too large and complicated I can just leave it as is and learn to deal with it.

Comment: [Website to see example](http://popstops.com)